# Google Apps Script Update Column S when there's a change and add new data below it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

so I have this code that I got here in which it updates column B when it detects change and also adds new data below it.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // 1. Retrieve values from the source and target sheets.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var [srcSheet, targetSheet] = ['Source Sheet', 'Target Sheet'].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));
  var [srcValues, targetValues] = [[srcSheet, "A2:S"], [targetSheet, "A2:S"]].map(s => s[0].getLastRow() == 1 ? [] : s[0].getRange(s[1] + s[0].getLastRow()).getValues());

  // 2. Create objects for searching values of the column "A".
  var [srcObj, targetObj] = [srcValues, targetValues].map(e => e.reduce((o, [a, ...b]) => (o[a] = b, o), {}));

  // 3. Check update values at the target sheet.
  var updatedValues = targetValues.map(([a, ...b]) => [a, ...(srcObj[a] || b)]);
  // 4. Check append values.
  var appendValues = srcValues.reduce((ar, [a, ...b]) => {
    if (!targetObj[a]) ar.push([a, ...b]);
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // 5. Update the target sheet.
  var values = [...updatedValues, ...appendValues];
  targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

But what I want right now is to update the column S instead of Column B, though I am a bit clueless on how I'm going to do it.

Comment: In order to correctly understand your questio, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images?

Comment: Here is the sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kQ_hiRjt_KHBC9PSwbNA8RzrNmIXP8Tnc4uMCXjxrss/edit?usp=sharing column S in source sheet tends to update every once in a while, and I want to update it also when I am encoding data when there's an update

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, "N2:X" of "Source Sheet" have no value of "Order ID", "Order Status",,,. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your expected situation. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: sorry about that, I have pasted the code as raw and didn't match it with the sample sheet, already edited the code to match the sample sheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your this question, you don't want to check the column "A". You want to check only the column "S". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Column A will be the basis or ID and then update column S

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the detail of `Column A will be the basis or ID and then update column S`?

Comment: the same as before, where it will check column A and update column S

Comment: In your situation, the same IDs are used in the column "A" of "Source Sheet" sheet?

Comment: yes, the same as column A of source sheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, when all values are copied from the source sheet to the destination sheet as an overwrite, is that your expected goal? Sorry. I might not be able to still understand your question.

Comment: no, it should add data, and if there is an update too the existing data in target sheet, it should be update. Just like what you did in the first one, but in this case, instead of updating column B, we need to update column S

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, both source sheet and destination sheet are modified. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected output values when both the source sheet and destination sheet are modified. But, I would like to support you. So, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly imagine your goal, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue immediately. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: hmm, the code above, it comes from you, months before, and what it does is it captures the data from source sheet, add the data to the bottom and if there is an update in column B, it update column B in target sheet. But now, I just need a little bit of modification that instead of column B, we need to update it in column S

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that when I could correctly imagine your situation that both the source sheet and destination sheet are modified, I can think of the solution. But, I cannot still imagine your goal. By this, I cannot think of a solution. This is due to my very poor English skill. I really apologize for this.

Comment: please refer to your answer in my question before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70014103/google-apps-script-to-find-and-update-rows-in-target-sheet-by-unique-id-and-add

We just need to update the column S instead of column B

Comment: Although I asked in my 1st comment, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images? I can understand the sample input situation in your provided sample Spreadsheet. Can you provide the sample output situations you expect? In the current stage, I cannot understand your expected situation that both the source sheet and destination sheet are modified. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: updated the sample sheet, pls see target sheet column S

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I asked `In your situation, both source sheet and destination sheet are modified. Is my understanding correct?`, you said `yes, that is correct`. When I saw your updated sample Spreadsheet, it seems that it seems that a sample that the "Target Sheet" is modified. In this case, do you want to update "Source Sheet"? If "Source Sheet" is modified, do you want to update "Target Sheet"? In this case, how do you check which sheet was modified?

Comment: sorry if I confuse you. I want to update the target sheet. And source sheet is modified

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I want to update the target sheet. And source sheet is modified` and your updated Spreadsheet, in this case, I think that when the target sheet is overwritten by the source sheet, this might be your expected situation. But, I'm worried that I might not be able to still understand your expected situation. If I misunderstood your expected situation, I apologize again.

Comment: based on your first code, it didn't overwrite the existing data in target sheet, it just adds the new data, and if there is some mismatch data from source sheet, it just updates those data

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still imagine your expected situation. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your question which is easy for you immediately. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: If you can give me time to try to understand your expected situation. I'm glad.

Comment: I think it will be better if you will focus on the code that you gave me last time and just modify it of instead updating column B, it should update column S

Comment: I have updated the sample sheet again and paste the code: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kQ_hiRjt_KHBC9PSwbNA8RzrNmIXP8Tnc4uMCXjxrss/edit#gid=0

so that it will be clear what it does.

In that code, it updates the column B of target sheet if there is an update from Source sheet based on Column A, and will add new data if target sheet doesn't have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to look for an answer and found this one, though what it does is it updates the whole row instead of the specific column that I want to update, but I think this will work fine for now:

```js
function Test() {
  // 1. Retrieve values from the source and target sheets.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var [srcSheet, targetSheet] = ['Source Sheet', 'Target Sheet'].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));
  var [srcValues, targetValues] = [[srcSheet, "A2:S"], [targetSheet, "A2:S"]].map(s => s[0].getLastRow() == 1 ? [] : s[0].getRange(s[1] + s[0].getLastRow()).getValues());

  // 2. Create objects for searching values of the column "A".
  var [srcObj, targetObj] = [srcValues, targetValues].map(e => e.reduce((o, [a, ...b]) => (o[a] = b, o), {}));

  // 3. Check update values at the target sheet.
  var updatedValues = targetValues.map(([a, ...b]) => [a, ...(srcObj[a] || b)]);
  // 4. Check append values.
  var appendValues = srcValues.reduce((ar, [a, ...b]) => {
    if (!targetObj[a]) ar.push([a, ...b]);
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // 5. Update the target sheet.
  var values = [...updatedValues, ...appendValues];
  targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```