# Find and update rows in target worksheet by unique ID and add unique rows if unique ID is not in the target worksheet using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

There is a list in [source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U4H-2Uf9ENNGB-fPLVgelw_39JMrwWLa5LlPZ1r3puM/copy) sheet. Now when the user makes any change to the status/action fields here and clicks "Submit", it should search for a match using the ticket number in column A in [target](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17rHvoNNR1ogiguA1-zyISmZZ5PDzp5mqAG-ercxe60k/copy) sheet, either update the existing line item with status/action fields from the source or make a new entry in the last row in target sheet.

Lucky that I was able to find a script that is able to make this happen between two tabs in the same sheet, but I'm not able to make it work between different worksheets. Is this something that anyone could help me solve?

```
function UpdateFunction() {
  // 1. Retrieve values from the source and target sheets.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var [srcSheet, targetSheet] = ['Source', 'Copy of Source'].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));
  var [srcValues, targetValues] = [[srcSheet, "A2:H"], [targetSheet, "A2:H"]].map(s => s[0].getLastRow() == 1 ? [] : s[0].getRange(s[1] + s[0].getLastRow()).getValues());

  // 2. Create objects for searching values of the column "A".
  var [srcObj, targetObj] = [srcValues, targetValues].map(e => e.reduce((o, [a, ...b]) => (o[a] = b, o), {}));

  // 3. Check update values at the target sheet.
  var updatedValues = targetValues.map(([a, ...b]) => [a, ...(srcObj[a] || b)]);
  // 4. Check append values.
  var appendValues = srcValues.reduce((ar, [a, ...b]) => {
    if (!targetObj[a]) ar.push([a, ...b]);
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // 5. Update the target sheet.
  var values = [...updatedValues, ...appendValues];
  targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Thanks in advance,
G

Comment: Your code looks very similar to this code[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70014103/google-apps-script-to-find-and-update-rows-in-target-sheet-by-unique-id-and-add] provided  by Tanaike and yet you offered no attribution for the author

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here and I'm not sure how to offer an attribution. May I ask you to teach me how?

Comment: The code provided does not find and update the entry in the Target sheet. Instead it copies the last row from the Source and replaces the first row in Target sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Update sheets from different spreadsheets

```
function UpdateFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Source");
  const vs1 = sh1.getRange("A2:H" + sh1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const sh2 = dss.getSheetByName("Destination");
  const vs2 = sh2.getRange("A2:H" + sh2.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const id2 = vs2.map(r => r['id2index']).flat();
  let d = 0;
  vs1.forEach((r,i) => {
    let idx = id2.indexOf(r['id1index'])
    if(~idx) {
      sh2.getRange(idx + 2,1,1,r.length).setValues([r]);
      sh1.deleteRow(i + 2 - d++);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This is showing the general methodology for using different spreadsheets. Of course when you use `openById(id)`, you need to include a parameter value (as a string) for the id. [Doc Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)